# Help with legal interpretation: Employment termination bonus repayment

Tags: contract-law, employment

> If you voluntarily terminate employment with the Company or for any reason fail to return from a non-job-protected leave of absence prior to one year of employment anniversary date, you will be responsible for repayment of the signing bonus in full to the Company on your last day of employment

If I started working on 1st Jan 2019, till when do I need to work in order to keep full signing bonus while leaving the company. Is it 1st Jan 2020, or 1st Jan 2021 ??

Comment: What makes you think it might be 1st Jan 2021?

Comment: i was wondering if it could be interpreted as `One year from employment anniversary` which adds another year.

Comment: I see. Then no. It means one year total. The answer (+1) by Ron Beyer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 1 year from your employment date (the "anniversary"), so if you started on Jan 1, 2019, you can quit on or after Jan 1, 2020.

Comment: Glad to know. thank you so much @Ron.

Comment: Jan 2nd, in most countries, as Jan 1st is a holiday ;)

Comment: @Trish lots of people work on holidays, for the context of this question though, and a legal definition of it, Jan 1 is the correct date, even if it's a holiday.